# How to stop barbell rolling back to extend wrist in benchpress?

Tags: bench-press, wrist

Some times when I bench press, I notice that the barbell likes to roll back along the surface of my palm to extend my wrist. Today I believe I got a wrist sprain due to it.

What could I do to stop this from happening? Tips?

Answer (score 1):

Wear wrist wraps on your heaviest sets. Wrist wraps provide support to your wrists and prevent extension. You probably don’t need them on lighter sets, but fatigue/lack of strength likely lead to unwanted wrist extension on heavier sets, or sets later in your workout. Just get a set of wraps made for pressing.

Comment: Do you have recommendations?

Comment: I wear SBD, but they’re probably more expensive than what you need. Rogue has a more economical, high quality offering, but I’m not sure they do international shipping.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're holding the bar incorrectly. In a bench press, the bar should be gripped with an extended wrist, not a straight wrist. The bar should sit extremely low on the pinky finger side of the hand, over the pisiform bone, which sits directly in line with the ulna bone of the forearm.

See the grip section of the [StrongLifts bench press guide](https://stronglifts.com/bench-press/) for imagery.

Comment: The article says opposite to what you said